# Problema al añadir un web service en proyecto asp.net core 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice

Obengo el siguiente error al tratar de añadir un web service:

http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/consultas.php?wsdl

An error occurred while attempting to find services at 'http://xxx.xx.xx.xx/consultas.php?wsdl'. The encoding in the declaration 'ISO-8859-1' does not match the encoding of the document 'utf-8'. (details)

Alguién sabe como solucionarle les agradeceria un mundo.

Comment: Agrega tu código por favor :)

Comment: Solo al crear la solución, le doy a Connected services -> add connected services -> Microsoft WFC web service reference provider luego copio la Url y Click en Go, en status me sale el error, no es error de codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el servicio consultas.php?wsdl esta declarando que su encoding es **ISO-8859-1** pero el texto mostrado esta en **utf-8**.

Esa insonsistencia es detectada por las herramientas de Visual Studio y lanzan el error.

Para repararlo es necesario revisar el servicio consultas.php y verificar que el encoding sea igual al texto mostrado.